# Criar um JSON e adicionar elementos dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Queria saber como fazer para criar um JSON e então ir adicionando elementos dinamicamente.

O JSON inicial precisa ser assim:

```
{
        id: Lime.Guid(),
        type: "application/vnd.lime.collection+json",
        to: "128271320123982@messenger.gw.msging.net",
        content: {
            itemType: "application/vnd.lime.document-select+json",
            items: [ ] 
        } 
}
```

Então eu preciso ir adicionando elementos em `Items` dinamicamente, baseado em um array que eu tenho. 
Cada item será da forma:

```
{
    header: {
      type: "application/vnd.lime.media-link+json",
      value: {
        title: "Title",
        text: "This is a first item",
        type: "image/jpeg",
        uri: "http://www.isharearena.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/wallpaper-281049.jpg"
       }
    }
}
```

Eu crio ele da seguinte maneira em meu código:

```
messageCarousel =  '{ ' +
            'id: Lime.Guid(), ' +
            'type: "application/vnd.lime.collection+json",' +
            'to: "128271320123982@messenger.gw.msging.net",' +
            'content: { ' +
                'itemType: "application/vnd.lime.document-select+json", ' +
                'items: [ ] '+ 
            '}' ;
```

E então vou adicionando os `Items`:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(messageCarousel);
messageCarousel[items].push('{ header: ' +
    ' { type: "application/vnd.lime.media-link+json", ' +
    'value: { ' +
    'title: Name, ' +
    'type: "image/jpeg", ' +
    'uri: Uri }}' );
messageCarousel = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Alguém pode me dizer o que está errado e como devo fazer isso da melhor maneira?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não precisa criar o `json` como string para depois parsear.

```js
// somente para mock
var Lime = { 

  Guid: function () {
    return '123456789'
  }
};

var messageCarousel  = {
  id: Lime.Guid(),
  type: "application/vnd.lime.collection+json",
  to: "128271320123982@messenger.gw.msging.net",
  content: {
      itemType: "application/vnd.lime.document-select+json",
      items: [ ] 
  } 
};

// add um item nos items
messageCarousel.content.items.push({
    header: {
      type: "application/vnd.lime.media-link+json",
      value: {
         title: "Title",
         text: "This is a first item",
         type: "image/jpeg",
         uri: "http://www.isharearena.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/wallpaper-281049.jpg"
      }
   }
});

// debug
alert('Veja o console para mais detalhes');
console.log(messageCarousel);
```

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou :3